# Asp.NET Identity is working sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-identity

This is my configuration.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    CookieName = "LoginCookie", 
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),

    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
             .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
              validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
              regenerateIdentity: 
                        (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
 });
```

The problem is that it work at first, let say the first 30 minutes but after that is stop working. I have check in Google Chrome and the cookie is not being added. No errors on the server and User Name and Password is working because when I enter a incorrect one I get the "try again" message. After re publishing the project everything start working and then the same problem again.

Comment: Check the timeout value for your cookie

Comment: I have change that without luck. When I publish the project everything work fine but after some time, I try to login and does not work. When I check the cookie is is never been added and the screen only refresh not error.

Comment: The cookie doesn't get set because there is currently a bug in Identity that always sets a non-persistent cookie when you use OnValidateIdentity to regenerate the cookie.

Comment: Then what can be done or when is it going to get fixed.